# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^3}$ for $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: fourier-series, closed-form

We have to find the closed form of the following series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^3}$$
for $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi)$. We tried to use the following form of the sine $$\sin(n\theta)=\frac{e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}}{2i}$$

but after some calculations it didnt seem to work, because of the $n^3$ in the denominator. So we also tried filling in the power series of the sine, but this also didnt help us much. I think we are missing an important example of a power series. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%28-1%29%5En%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%28n%5Ctheta%29%7D%7Bn%5E3%7D) finds a non-elementary solution.

Comment: @lhf Already tried that, it must be a lot simpler since it was in a test.

Comment: $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin (nx)}{n}$$ is a relatively well-known Fourier series (of a really simple function). Integrate that twice and you get your series.

Comment: It's the imaginary part of $\sum \frac{(-z)^n}{n^3}$ where $z=e^{i\theta}$.  This explains the non-elementary function comes from in Wolfram Alpha - which uses $Li_{3}(-e^{i\theta})$ where $Li_3(z)=\sum \frac{z^n}{n^3}$.

Comment: Daniel Fisher had given the very simple solution and the Fourier series he suggested is that of  x/2.  This Fourier series converges to x/2.  So integrating x/2 and Fourier series twice term by term and adjusting the constant term gives you the answer.  I would just like to make a comment that familiarity with simple functions and their Fourier series gives you a base line to thinking about behaviour of Fourier series and their convergence.  Bringing in transform method with Mellin transform, Gamma function, Contour integration seems like using a sledge hammer for a simple job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it must be a lot simpler since it was in a test.

I guess that rules out [Marco Cantarini](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/186170/marco-cantarini)'s impressive use of the Mellin transform as the expected or intended solution - unless it was a test for a course dealing with the Mellin transform.

More likely, it was expected that one recognises a related Fourier series. Defining

$$f(\theta) := \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\sin (n\theta)}{n^3},$$

it is easy to see

$$f''(\theta) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin (n\theta)}{n},$$

and that is a Fourier series that one sees occasionally.

We have

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \theta \sin (n\theta)\,d\theta = \biggl[-\frac{\theta\cos (n\theta)}{n}\biggr]_{-\pi}^\pi + \frac{1}{n}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos (n\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2\pi}{n},$$

and so

$$f''(\theta) = \frac{\theta}{2}.$$

Integrating that, it follows that

$$f'(\theta) = \frac{\theta^2}{4} + c,$$

and using the constraint

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f'(\theta)\,d\theta = 0$$

from the periodicity of $f$, we find $c = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}$. Then integrating once more, we obtain (this time, the integration constant is easily seen to be $0$)

$$f(\theta) = \frac{\theta^3}{12} - \frac{\pi^2\theta}{12}.$$

If one doesn't recognise the Fourier series of $f''$ [or maybe already that of $f'$], things are more difficult. However, if one has the idea to write

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin (n\theta)}{n} = \operatorname{Im} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} e^{in\theta},$$

which in the context of Fourier transforms doesn't seem a too far-fetched idea, one may recognise the Taylor series of

$$\log \bigl(1 + e^{i\theta}\bigr)$$

in that - for an attempt to find the value, it is not necessary to go into the details of convergence; if one has found the candidate, one can verify it in many ways. Now

$$1 + e^{i\theta} = \bigl(e^{i\theta/2} + e^{-i\theta/2}\bigr)e^{i\theta/2} = 2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\cdot e^{i\theta/2},$$

so $\operatorname{Im} \log \bigl(1 + e^{i\theta}) = \frac{\theta}{2} + 2\pi k(\theta)$, and it's not hard to see that $k(\theta) \equiv 0$ is the correct choice.

If one feels at home with distributions, one can recognise the Fourier series of $f'''$ as that of $\frac{1}{2} - \pi \delta_\pi$, but that is probably also beyond what can be expected.

Answer (score 6):

We have, assuming $\theta \neq 0$, $$\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k^{3}}=\theta^{3}\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k^{3}\theta^{3}}
 $$ and we can use the fact that the Mellin transform identity for harmonic sums with base function $g(x)$ is $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\lambda_{k}g\left(\mu_{k}x\right),\, s\right)=\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\lambda_{k}}{\mu_{k}^{s}}\, g\left(s\right)^{*}
 $$ where $g\left(s\right)^{*}$ is the Mellin transform of $g\left(x\right)$ . So in this case we have $$\lambda_{k}=\left(-1\right)^{k},\,\mu_{k}=k,\, g\left(x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^{3}}
 $$ and so its Mellin transform is $$g\left(s\right)^{*}=\Gamma\left(s-3\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi\left(s-3\right)\right)
 $$and observig that $$\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\lambda_{k}}{\mu_{k}^{s}}=\left(2^{1-s}-1\right)\zeta\left(s\right)
 $$ we have $$\theta^{3}\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k^{3}\theta^{3}}=\frac{\theta^{3}}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}}\left(2^{1-s}-1\right)\zeta\left(s\right)\Gamma\left(s-3\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi\left(s-3\right)\right)\theta^{-s}ds=
 $$ $$\frac{\theta^{3}}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}}Q\left(s\right)\theta^{-s}ds.
 $$ Note that sine term cancels poles in at odd negative integers, zeta cancels poles at even negative integers and $\left(2^{1-s}-1\right)$ cancels the pole of zeta at $s=1
 $ . So we have poles only at $s=0,2$ and the compute is $$\underset{s=0}{\textrm{Res}}\left(Q\left(s\right)\theta^{-s}\right)=\frac{1}{12}
 $$ $$\underset{s=2}{\textrm{Res}}\left(Q\left(s\right)\theta^{-s}\right)=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12\theta^{2}}
 $$ and so we have $$\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k^{3}}=\frac{\theta^{3}}{12}-\frac{\pi^{2}\theta}{12}.
 $$

Comment: I'm always amazed by the power of complex analysis, what a neat application.

Answer (score 3):

Combining Marco's solution with the polylog solution ...
$$
\text{Im}\;\text{Li}_3(-e^{it})= \frac{t^3-\pi^2 t}{12},
\qquad -\pi < t < \pi
$$
But of course everyone knows that!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the Fourier series of an odd function, and it converges uniformly, since
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg|(-1)^n \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^3} \Bigg|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}.
$$
You can research a bit through the literature and look for some text in which the exact value of the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6}
$$
is computed (if you know about Parseval's theorem you will understand why), and the function you are looking for will most probably appear in that text.

Also, just as a matter of language, such series are not called power series, but trigonometric series (due to the sine). Power series have the form $\sum a_nz^n$.

Comment: Given the exponent of $n$, I would look at a quasi-sinusoid formed of two arcs of parabola.