# Sum $\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \frac{(-1)^n \sin(n\theta)}{n^3}$ using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

The following question appeared on an old complex analysis exam. (The only tools we have learned are simple series for $\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$ etc., the residue theorem and some tools from real analysis like the Weierstrass M-test.)

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geqslant 1} \frac{(-1)^n \sin(n\theta)}{n^3}$ for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

I first believed this had to be evaluated using the residue theorem, but after seeing [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850565/calculating-series-using-residue-theorem-sum-n-0-infty-left-frac-1) I tried to manipulate it by taking the derivative.

Since $\displaystyle \left\vert\frac{(-1)^n\sin(n\theta)}{n^3} \right\vert\leq \frac{1}{n^3}$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}1/n^3<\infty$, it is uniformly convergent for all $\theta$ by the Weierstrass M-test.

We can rewrite the sum as $\operatorname{Im}\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-e^{i\theta})^n}{n^3}$. I tried differentiating the sum, to make use of the closed form $\sum_{n\geq 1}z^n/n=-\log(1-z)$ for $|z|<1$, but this only becomes a big mess.

What is the right way to evaluate this sum using complex analysis?

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}{\frac{{{(-{{e}^{i\theta }})}^{n}}}{{{n}^{3}}}}=L{{i}_{3}}\left( -{{e}^{-i\theta }} \right)$$

Comment: @logo I am not familiar with the $\operatorname{Li}_3$ function, this is just an elementary complex analysis exam question.

Comment: A cheating way is to notice that the Fourier coefficients of $t (\pi^2 - t^2)$ are equal to
$$\frac 1 {2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi t (\pi^2 - t^2) e^{-i k t} dt =
\frac {6 (-1)^{k + 1} i} {k^3} [k \neq 0].$$

Comment: @Maxim Fourier series are also not treated in my course, I am looking for a more elementary method I guess..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351253/closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-1n-frac-sinn-thetan3-for-theta-i